# Is there a way to pass a NER spacy model a bank of words that are a custom label?

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition

I have a bank of 6,000 words that correspond to a custom label. The NER was already trained on 300 example sentences with the custom label annotated. Is there a way to pass the 6,000 words to the NER to be recognized in the same context as the 300 examples?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a specific example of what you want to do? It sounds like you have a list of specific terms you always want to label a certain way, like "Spain" is always a "COUNTRY". To do that you can just use the [rule based matching](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching) in spaCy.

For your case specifically I'd use a pattern file. You can make a pattern file like this:

```
{"label": "ORG", "pattern": "Apple"}
{"label": "ORG", "pattern": "Microsoft"}
{"label": "ORG", "pattern": "Something"}
... all your other info ...
```

And then, supposing that file is named `patterns.jsonl`, you can load it like this:

```
ruler = nlp.add_pipe("entity_ruler").from_disk("patterns.jsonl")
```

And that'll tag your words.

Do read the whole section in the docs though, it describes the details of using rule-based and statistical models together.